# Internet Explorer HTTPS cross-domain links problem

Tags: internet-explorer, https

I have a very strange problem over I.E (version 6 and 7).

On one server we have apache listening HTTPS on port 443 (custom php app) and tomcat listening HTTPS on port 18443 (pentaho) and each web application have a link to the other.

Links from 443 to 18443 are working fine, but links from 18443 to 443 are not working and we get a 404 response; after this first response, refreshing the page or simply hitting again the "go" button will display the page properly. Also writing the url directly in the address bar while staying in the 18443 application would not display the page within the first try, but will do within the second try.

On firefox everything works ok, but we must make it work on I.E.

Both sites certificate are not trusted but self-signed, would this be the problem?

Any advice is welcome.

Comment: What kind of addresses - Intranet IPs, host names, remote servers?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, anyway they are Intranet IPs, same ip for both applications as they are on the same server, only the port is different